# ActionBarSherlock, activities or fragments?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using `ActionBarSherlock` with some tabs. One of these, registers some user data. My purpose is to pass this data, i.e. username, through the other tabs.

So, my question is which way is better to achieve this? By using a main `SherlockActivity` and `SherlockFragments` for each of the tabs or by using `SherlockActivity` for each of the tabs and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple example for tabs using ActionBarSherlock: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java

If you want to use Fragments in your tabs, use a `SherlockFragmentActivity` instead and do the appropriate fragment transactions in `onTabSelected`.